# How to create database and table using lua program in corona sdk?

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I am new to lua programming, I don't know about how to create database, In that create tables and retrieving it.

I want to create a database and tables only for first time. I need to insert the values into table and I want to retrieve the list from table.

I don't know how to start because I am beginner for lua programing.  Can you guys please help me or suggest any tutorial to go through.

Please help me

Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Comment: I want to create them in one .lua file and want to call them from required .lua file. How can I call them to insert, retrieve update and delete from another .lua file.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed http://wiki.garrysmod.com/?title=LUA:SQLite_Tutorial for sql lite & Lua tutorial and it was good. Before start, you need to install or copy lua dlls/modules into system path so that lua db module should be able to locate the database.

LuaSQL is good choice for client side library..

http://www.capricorn76.com/c76_scriptengine_docsdk/luasql/index.html

Comment: @ Gopalakrishnan :Thanks dude, I will look into it, then I will get back to you.

Comment: How to access database (sqlite3) using lua?

Comment: I got done with inserting the values into the table and I want to know how to update the inserted record in the table.Need syntax for tat.As I am new to Corona I need help from ur side.

Answer (score 0):

You mention Corona in your tags, although you didn't mention that in your question. That makes a difference, since Corona has built-in support for SQLite but not any other kind of database.

There's documentation on their website about how to use the database functionality: http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/data-storage

Note that their examples all use [[ ]] syntax for the database commands, but I find it looks better and is easier to understand to use " "

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I will explain the way I do it:

1. Download Sqlite Browser (https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases)
2. Create an empty database
3. Put it in the your project folder
4. In your code copy it to the system.DocumentsDirectory:

   ```
   local function copyDatabase()
       util.copyFile( "model.db", system.ResourceDirectory, db_name, system.DocumentsDirectory, false )
   end
   ```

**util.copyFile:**

```
function M.copyFile( srcName, srcPath, dstName, dstPath, overwrite )

local results = false

local srcPath = M.doesFileExist( srcName, srcPath )

if ( srcPath == false ) then
    return nil  -- nil = source file not found
end

--check to see if destination file already exists
if not ( overwrite ) then
    if ( M.doesFileExist( dstName, dstPath ) ) then
        return 1  -- 1 = file already exists (dont overwrite)
    end
end

--copy the source file to the destination file
local rfilePath = system.pathForFile( srcName, srcPath )
local wfilePath = system.pathForFile( dstName, dstPath )

local rfh = io.open( rfilePath, "rb" )
local wfh = io.open( wfilePath, "wb" )

if not ( wfh ) then
    print( "writeFileName open error!" )
    return false
else
    --read the file from 'system.ResourceDirectory' and write to the destination directory
    local data = rfh:read( "*a" )
    if not ( data ) then
        print( "read error!" )
        return false
    else
        if not ( wfh:write( data ) ) then
            print( "write error!" )
            return false
        end
    end
end

results = 2  -- 2 = file copied successfully!

--clean up file handles
rfh:close()
wfh:close()

return results
end
```

**To open the database:**

```
local function openDatabase()
    local path = system.pathForFile( db_name, system.DocumentsDirectory )
    db = sqlite3.open( path ) 
end
```

**To create some tables**

```
local function createTables()
    -- I dont create a Primary Key manually as Sqlite creates ROWID for us
    db:exec( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (category TEXT, description TEXT, icon_location TEXT )" )
end
```

You can easily update and insert records using db:exec (db being your local variable to the database). db:exec returns a 0 if the query was completed without any errors.